# AWS: Migration to Fargate Spot

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-fargate

i am currently on **AWS** with **ECS** instances running on **Fargate**.
I would like to migrate to **Fargate Spot** because of the pricing, but I notice that my containers can have downtime, if i scheduled for example 2 tasks for each instance, can I be sure that there will not be such downtime? If no, there is a way to get rid of that downtime with Fargate Spot.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately you can never guarantee that Amazon would not want the availability back.

For this reason depending on your usecase you can combine on demand and spot for fargate to account for a sudden loss of spot instances. This will help to mitigate in case you lose your Fargate Spot at sudden notice.

Some AWS recommendations for Fargate Spot are:

- Fargate Spot is great for stateless, fault-tolerant workloads, but don’t rely solely on Spot Tasks for critical workloads, configure a mix of regular Fargate Tasks
- Applications running on Fargate Spot should be fault-tolerant
- Handle interruptions gracefully by catching SIGTERM signals

If you’re trying to save money but need a consistent workload then a [compute savings plan](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/pricing/) might be more appropriate (or combine with spot).

For more information take a look at the [Deep dive into Fargate Spot to run your ECS Tasks for up to 70% less](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deep-dive-into-fargate-spot-to-run-your-ecs-tasks-for-up-to-70-less/) article.